# How to give users multiple entries in a giveaway

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been trying to make a bot with discord.py that checks all the users' statuses on a server. I made the bot go through a loop every one hour and add one entry to any user with the status 'status'. That part works well, however, I do not know how to give users with more entries a higher chance to win. For example, in a server with 3 people, person 1 has 1 entry, 2 has 2 entries, and 3 has 2 entries. I would give person 2 and 3 both 2 times the win chance of person 1. There are no errors since I'm just trying to figure out what to do.

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("developer")
async def startloop(ctx):
    print(data)
    while True:
        allmembers = ctx.guild.members
        for i in allmembers:
            for x in i.activities:
                if isinstance(x, discord.CustomActivity):
                    if str(x) == 'status':
                        print('status detected')
                        for d in data:
                            if d['id'] == i.id:
                                d['entries'] = d['entries'] + 1
                                await ctx.send('test')
                                print(data)
                                pass
        time.sleep(3600)
@client.command()
@commands.has_role("developer")
async def gstart(ctx):
    #trying to make the giveaway command
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a list of numbers: [1 ... n]. N is the total number of entries. Then choose a random number in between the range of 1 through n. The person who holds the nth entry will win the raffle. You will need to keep track of the user's entries in a list. For example user 1 may have entries: [1, 2, 3]. User 2: [4, 5, 6, 7], and so on. The random number will be in some user's entry list.

Comment: but how would I know who holds the nth entry?

Comment: just edited my answer to answer this